# インストールに失敗したカーネル(ソースからビルド)の削除方法を教えてください

Tags: centos, kernel

パッケージマネージャを使わずインストールしたカーネルはどのように削除すればよいですか？
カーネル4.16.7をソースからビルドしインストールしましたが、起動しないため削除したいです。
ディストリビューションはCentOS7を使っています。

Answer (score 1):

本家SOに関連質問と回答があります。
https://stackoverflow.com/q/25993363/2322778

1. `/boot`と`/lib/modules`以下にコンパイルでインストールされたバージョンのファイルを個別に削除
2. grubの設定を更新